# How to make a POST request with JSON string?

Tags: php, json, http, post

How can I do this without cURL?

I will not having problem parsing JSON string but how can I make a POST request with one to return a json string contain data??

```
$dataFeed=$_GET["dataFeed"]; 
$url='urlneedtopostto';

$data=array('data'=>$dataFeed);
$jsonString=json_encode($data);
```

How can I post request this?

Comment: Use file_get_contents();

Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668609/how-to-post-data-to-url-with-php-without-curl

Comment: if you want to use $_POST you must create a form to submit it. here's the helpfull [link](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html)

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano Actually, you don't have to. Using cURL or file_get_contents with a context would do the same.

Comment: so i should use markR's link?

Comment: I tried what mark said and I get bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a jQuery post request?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: sorry solution has to be in pure php.